# Return To Main Menu Button not functional in Corona SDK

Tags: menu, return, coronasdk

I can not get the Restart or Main Menu buttons to work after you WIN or FAIL the game. Can anyone point me in the right direction. I dont want to have to use a storyboard, unless it is the only way.... (the code for win fail is at the very bottom)

```
--[Colors Used]
--389bff (Blue)
--ff3938 (Red)

-- Hide Status Bar

display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

-- Physics

local physics = require('physics')
physics.start()
physics.setGravity(0,0)
--physics.setDrawMode('hybrid')

-- Graphics

-- [Background]

local bg = display.newImage('bg.png')

-- [Title View]

local titleBg
local playBtn
local creditsBtn
local titleView

-- [Credits]

local creditsView

-- Game Background

local gameBg

-- Circles Group

local circles

-- Walls 

local left
local right
local top
local bottom

-- Score TextField

local score

-- Variables

local lastY
local lastX

-- Functions

local Main = {}
local startButtonListeners = {}
local showCredits = {}
local hideCredits = {}
local showGameView = {}
local gameListeners = {}
local onTouch = {}
local onCollision = {}
local alert = {}


-- Main Function

function Main()
    titleBg = display.newImage('title.png', 0, 100)
    playBtn = display.newImage('playBtn.png', 200, 240)
    creditsBtn = display.newImage('creditsBtn.png', 200, 290)
    titleView = display.newGroup(titleBg, playBtn, creditsBtn)

    startButtonListeners('add')
end

function startButtonListeners(action)
    if(action == 'add') then
        playBtn:addEventListener('tap', showGameView)
        creditsBtn:addEventListener('tap', showCredits)
    else
        playBtn:removeEventListener('tap', showGameView)
        creditsBtn:removeEventListener('tap', showCredits)
    end
end

function showCredits:tap(e)
    playBtn.isVisible = false
    creditsBtn.isVisible = false
    creditsView = display.newImage('credits.png', 0, display.contentHeight)

    lastY = titleBg.y
    lastX = titleBg.x
    transition.to(titleBg, {time = 300, y = (display.contentHeight * 0.5) - (titleBg.height - 15), x = (display.contentWidth * 0.5) - (titleBg.width * 0.5) + 55 })
    transition.to(creditsView, {time = 300, y = (display.contentHeight * 0.5) + 35, onComplete = function() creditsView:addEventListener('tap', hideCredits) end})
end

function hideCredits:tap(e)
    transition.to(creditsView, {time = 300, y = display.contentHeight + 25, onComplete = function() creditsBtn.isVisible = true playBtn.isVisible = true creditsView:removeEventListener('tap', hideCredits) display.remove(creditsView) creditsView = nil end})
    transition.to(titleBg, {time = 300, y = lastY, x = lastX});
end

function showGameView:tap(e)
    transition.to(titleView, {time = 300, x = -titleView.height, onComplete = function() startButtonListeners('rmv') display.remove(titleView) titleView = nil end})

    -- [Add GFX]

    -- Game Background

    display.remove(bg)
    gameBg = display.newImage('gameBg.png')

    -- Walls

    left = display.newLine(0, 240, 0, 720)
    right = display.newLine(320, 240, 320, 720)
    top = display.newLine(160, 0, 480, 0)
    bottom = display.newLine(160, 480, 480, 480)

    -- Circles

    circles = display.newGroup()
    local color = 0

    for i = 1, 5 do
        local rx = 21 + math.floor(math.random() * (display.contentWidth - 42)) --was 21 and 42
        local ry = 21 + math.floor(math.random() * (display.contentHeight - 42))--was 21 and 42

        local cg = display.newCircle(rx, ry, 21)--was 21
        local label = display.newText('20',cg.x-6.5, cg.y-6.2, native.systemFontBold, 13) --text was 0
        cg.fillColor = color + (i*40)
        cg:setFillColor(cg.fillColor)
        local c = display.newGroup(cg, label)
        c.pressed = false
        c.name = 'c'
        c.radius = 21

        -- Circle Physics

        physics.addBody(c, 'dynamic', {radius = 21, bounce = 1})--was 21
        c:setLinearVelocity(50, 50)--was 100,100 = speed of balls on start

        circles:insert(c)
    end

    -- Walls Physics

    physics.addBody(left, 'static')
    physics.addBody(right, 'static')
    physics.addBody(top, 'static')
    physics.addBody(bottom, 'static')

    -- Score TextField

    score = display.newText('100', 257, 4, native.systemFont, 15) -- score was 0 not 100
    score:setTextColor(255, 252, 252)
    local total = display.newText('   / 100', 267, 4, native.systemFont, 15)
    total:setTextColor(255, 252, 252)

    gameListeners('add')
end

function gameListeners(action)
    if(action == 'add') then
        for i = 1, 5 do
            circles[i]:addEventListener('touch', onTouch)
            circles[i]:addEventListener('collision', onCollision)
        end
    else
        for i = 1, 5 do
            circles[i]:removeEventListener('touch', onTouch)
            circles[i]:removeEventListener('collision', onCollision)
        end
    end
end

function onTouch(e)
    if(e.phase == 'began') then
        e.target.pressed = true

        -- Decrease Counter

        score.text = tostring(tonumber(score.text) - 1)

        -- Decrease size

        e.target.radius = e.target.radius - 1

        -- Change Color

        e.target[1]:setFillColor(255,57,56)
    end

    if(e.phase == 'ended') then
        e.target.pressed = false
        -- Update physics

        local number = tostring(tonumber(e.target[2].text)-1)
        local r = e.target.radius
        local cg = display.newCircle(e.target.x, e.target.y, r)
        local label = display.newText(number ,cg.x-4.2, cg.y-6.2, native.systemFontBold, 13) -- was12.2
        cg:setFillColor(e.target[1].fillColor)
        cg.fillColor = e.target[1].fillColor
        local c = display.newGroup(cg, label)
        c.pressed = false
        c.name = 'c'
        c.radius = r
        circles:remove(e.target)
        physics.addBody(c, 'dynamic', {radius = r, bounce = 1})
        c:setLinearVelocity(50, 50)--this changes the speed once touched was100,100
        c:addEventListener('touch', onTouch)
        c:addEventListener('collision', onCollision)
        circles:insert(c)

        -- Move Textfield when number is 2 digit
        if(tonumber(number) > 9) then
            label.x = label.x - 3
        end

        -- Check if score has reached 0

        if(tonumber(score.text) <=0) then
            local bg = display.newImage('gameBg.png')
            transition.from(bg, {time = 500, alpha = 0, onComplete = alert('win')})
        end
    end
end

function onCollision(e)
    if(e.target.pressed and e.other.name == 'c') then
        -- Wait 0.1 seconds to stop physics
        timer.performWithDelay(100, function() physics.stop() end, 1)

        local r = e.target.radius
        local c = display.newCircle(e.target.x, e.target.y, r)
        c:setFillColor(255,57,56)

        gameListeners('rmv')
        transition.to(c, {time = 700, xScale = 500, yScale =  500, onComplete = alert('lost')}) --change from 25 to 50
    end
end

function alert(action)
    if(action == 'win') then
        local alertView = display.newImage('won.png', 0, 105)
        transition.from(alertView, {time = 300, y = -82, delay = 500})
        local alertView = display.newImage('replayWinBtn.png', 200, 240)
        transition.from(alertView, {time = 300, y = -82, delay = 500})
        local alertView = display.newImage('replayWinMenuBtn.png', 200, 290)
        transition.from(alertView, {time = 300, y = -82, delay = 500})
    else
        local alertView = display.newImage('lost.png', 0, 105)
        transition.from(alertView, {time = 300, y = -82, delay = 500})
        local alertView = display.newImage('replayLostBtn.png', 200, 240)
        transition.from(alertView, {time = 300, y = -82, delay = 500})
        local alertView = display.newImage('replayLostMenuBtn.png', 200, 290)
        transition.from(alertView, {time = 300, y = -82, delay = 500})
    end
end

Main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this

```
transition.from(bg, {time = 500, alpha = 0, onComplete = alert('win')})
```

to this

```
transition.from(bg, {time = 500, alpha = 0, onComplete = function()
    alert('win')
end})
```